# How do I detect whether an Eclipse build failed?

Tags: eclipse, ant, build-automation

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347698/how-do-i-automatically-export-a-war-after-java-build-in-eclipse), I now want to know how to stop an ANT script from executing if the preceding build failed.  I can't see a way in the Build setup in Eclipse of chaining builds together based on their success.

I think I am lookikng for either a way to pass the previous build status into my ANT script so I can terminate or to never call the ANT script at all if the first build fails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No native way, AFAIK.
What you can do is modify your ant script to check if .class files produced by Eclipse are newer than WAR. If not, stop.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines myself.  Looks like I need to learn a bit more ANT...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to store the success into a file. If you make sure the content of the file is a property file content the next ant task can use that file to fill in a property (like build.success) and can act on that.