# Want to upload war automatically on server if something get changed on local

Tags: java, war

I have been working on 3 Java Spring and Hibernate projects at a time. Every time if I make any changes on any of these three project then I have to create build again and manually I upload three builds to three different servers.

Is there any mechanism to avoid this manual process? Is there a tool or script that can check if I make changes to my code in Eclipse and save the files which will then commit the code and automatically build and upload the war file to the appropriate server?

This would save me a lot of time.

Comment: you can use [maven](http://maven.apache.org/)

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347698/how-do-i-automatically-export-a-war-after-java-build-in-eclipse?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need continous integration. Maven is a build tool and won't deploy on change.

Whereas a CI tool such as [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) will listen to your code reposiotry and every time a file is commited it will call then call whatver maven command you wish.

However re-reading your question, it looks like all you really need is a hot deploy development enivronment. Which is [quite easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6189031/106261).

Comment: Will SVN helps me on this ?

Comment: subversion is a code repository, I would recommend mercurial or git over subversion.

Answer (score 0):

If the projects are on maven, there are plugins for all major application servers.

Comment: what is maven ?> Sorry I dnt know this term

Comment: It is a software project management tool. It can do many many things in any step of the project build process.